# Element Scroll Into View not Working with Behavior Set to 'smooth'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, rxjs

I have a list of elements that are rendered to the view using `*ngFor`, the number of elements in the list in most cases will exceed the height of the list container element, so `overflow: auto` being used to make the container scrollable.

Each element in the list represents the occurrence of an event at a specific time in the past, the occurrence time of the event stored in UNIX timestamp format.

On the core layer, there is a `BehaviorSubject` that starts from the first event timestamp and emits the next value every 100 milliseconds.

Back to the representation layer, there's a subscription of the SubjectBehavroure mentioned above, that does the following on each received new value:

1. Look for the event in the list, that match the newly received value
2. If an event is found, it should be activated

   ```
    <div class="container" id="scroll">
     <div
       class="list-item"
       id="{{ event.timestamp }}"
       [ngClass]="{ active: event.active }"
       *ngFor="let event of timelineEvents"
     >
      <div class="event-details text">{{ event.timestamp }}</div>
     </div>
   </div>




    @Component({
     selector: 'events',
     templateUrl: './events.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./events.component.scss'],
   })
   export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
     timelineEvents: Array<FsTimeLineEvent> = [];
     currentTimeSubscription$: Subscription;
     startTimestamp: number;

     constructor(private eventFacade: eventFacade) {}

     ngOnInit(): void {
       this.currentTimeSubscription$ = this.eventFacade.currentTime$.subscribe(
         (currentTime) => {

           // get current timestamp value
           let currentTimestamp = currentTime + this.startTimestamp;

           // look for an event
           let currentEventIndex = this.timelineEvents.findIndex(
             (x) => x.timestamp >= currentTimestamp
           );

           // set the event to active
           this.setActiveEvent(currentEventIndex);
         }
       );
     }
     setActiveEvent(index) {
       this.timelineEvents.forEach((eve) => {
         eve.active = false;
       });

       let currentEvent = this.timelineEvents[index];
       currentEvent.active = true;

       let itemToScrollToView = document.getElementById(
         `${currentEvent.timestamp}`
       );

       if (itemToScrollToView)
         itemToScrollToView.scrollIntoView({
           behavior: 'smooth',
           block: 'center',
         });
     }
   }
   ```

How the event is activated?

1. Adding special CSS to it, simple border.
2. Scroll the event HTML Element into the center of the list container HTML element

The logic is working as expected, but only with scroll behavior set to 'auto'

```
let activeElement: HTMLElement = docment.getElementById(`${id}`)
activeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center' })
```

What I would love to achieve is smooth easy scrolling, I've tried to change the behavior of the scroll to 'smooth' but that disables the scrolling at all. Which makes no sense to me at all, like why this is happening?

I've made a ton of researches, I've tried to implement my own custom scrollIntoView function, but I've got nothing! I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser / system are you using for testing? Safari doesn't support `smooth.` And can you post a functional code snippet that shows the element not being able to do a smooth scroll into view?

Comment: @RichDeBourke I'm using chrome. I've added a code snippet to the questions, let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, your code snippet looks to be in Angular, which I don’t use (and your code won’t run in Stackoverflow’s snippet tool). If you could open your page in a browser, view and copy enough of the source code, CSS, and JavaScript into the snippet tool (the [<>] button) to see the problem, it would be easier to see your problem.

Comment: Define your 'itemToScrollIntoView' as an HTML Element and then see if its working. Somehting ilke: 'itemToScrollIntoView: HTMLElement = document.getElementById()'.

Comment: @RichDeBourke I've made a working code on stackblitz, and the wired thing it's scrolling smoothly, and the functionalities are working there!  Why is not working on my code? based on your experience what things will prevent the smooth scrolling behavior? 


Here's the link to the running code:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ruoqxd?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: @SrikarPhaniKumarMarti it's an HTML Element already, what do you mean?